# How does this code work? Specifically, the WorkerCompare struct

Tags: c++, simulation, stdvector, priority-queue

(Sorry if this question sounds vague. I'll add more information if needed.)

The task of the program is to simulate parallel processing. One solution I found on the internet contains this code which works but I don't know how. Specifically, why and how `WorkerCompare` was used:

```
class Worker {
    public:
        int id;
        long long nextFreeTime;
        Worker (int id) {
            this->id = id;
            nextFreeTime = 0;
        }
};

struct WorkerCompare {
    bool operator()(const Worker &w1, const Worker &w2) const {
        if(w1.nextFreeTime == w2.nextFreeTime)
            return w1.id > w2.id;
        else
            return w1.nextFreeTime > w2.nextFreeTime;
    }
};
```

This code was mainly used in this function:

```
void AssignJobs() {
    assigned_workers_.resize(jobs_.size());
    start_times_.resize(jobs_.size());
    priority_queue<Worker, vector<Worker>, WorkerCompare> pq;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_workers_; i++) {
        pq.push(Worker(i));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jobs_.size(); i++) {
        Worker freeThread = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        assigned_workers_[i] = freeThread.id;
        start_times_[i] = freeThread.nextFreeTime;
        freeThread.nextFreeTime += jobs_[i];
        pq.push(freeThread);
    }
  }
```

It adds elements to the vectors `assigned_workers_` and `start_times_` which lists the thread used to do a process as well as at what time the process started.

The full source code can be seen [here](https://github.com/akueisara/datastructures/blob/master/week%202/job_queue/job_queue.cpp).

Comment: You should read the documentation before using a class: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue. This is very basic knowledge that every C++ programmer should know. I highly recommend you reading a few C++ books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> priority_queue<Worker, vector<Worker>, WorkerCompare> pq;
> ```

I assume that this is the `std::priority_queue` from the standard library.

Priority queues work by **comparing** elements. That is what `WorkerCompare` is used for. It compares objects of type `Worker`.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, `pq` has a type `Worker` as indicated by the first parameter, and the `pq.push(Worker(i));` adds an element to the `vector<Worker>` indicated by the second parameter, and the `WorkerCompare` keeps the queue organized. Is that correct?

Comment: @CarlEricDoromal `vector<Worker>` is the type of container that the queue uses for internal storage. But yeah, that's pretty much it. See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2079303